# C# How to make webbrowser clickable

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I was wonder how can I fire an event when the user double click on my webbrowser component. Since it has no such event how it could be possible...

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it has `Clicked` event, you can do a workaround using a `Timer` or something.

Comment: The problem is even the onClick event hasn't handled... it has a previewkeydown event but it just handle the key strokes

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect double click on WebBrower control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826369/how-to-detect-double-click-on-webbrower-control)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a WPF matter :-)
There you would go with an Behaviour attached to the browser. See [this link](http://brianseekford.com/index.php/2010/08/31/mouse-double-click-for-wpf-in-mvvm-using-a-clean-behavior-with-command-binding/) for more information about this approach if you can alter your application (dependends on what you have done yet).

If you can't apply this solution, just bind a event handler to the click event and count click per time with respect to the mouse movement since the last click and if both conditions are true (two clicks in 0.2 secs, mouse hasn't moved more than 2px, for example) execute your double click code. The events you should use are `previewMOUSEdown` or `MOUSEdown`, not `KEYdown`.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for winforms.

Comment: @JohnIsaiahCarmona the illustrated approach  (second paragraph) should be applyable, don't know if it's called OnClicked or OnMouseDown, what's in a name? :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
// Call this where you want to create the event (let's say on the form load for example).
webBrowser1.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(webBrowser1_DoubleClick);

// This happens when the event is fired (so when you double click on the webbrowser control).
void webBrowser1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code
        }
```

Try this.

I don't know why you can't set this event via the designer :(, but this should work.

Comment: man it has no DoubleClick event, so it wouldn't be a good idea

Comment: Ooh, didn't know that, I don't have VS2010 open nor used a WebControl before. I didn't knew that the webcontrol doesn't have a DoubleClick event. Sorry